# Nant Version 0.92 escape ${}

Tags: asp.net, ant, nant

I'm having a hard time getting Nant to ignore ${xyz}. I know ${} is treated as a variable in nant, but how do i ignore since nlog config values also use the same format for variables.

Here are the options i tried:

```
$${xyz} produces => $${xyz}

${'${xyz}'} => Error, still treats the inner as variable
```

Comment: Could you give a little more details. I tried this locally (the second option) and seems to be working fine i.e. it prints ${xyz} and not the variable value.